# How can I solve the login and User page

Tags: php, xampp

I have encountered problem using php session. When I try to login using login form it goes to User page. That's fine but I try to use  address bar to change the URL, it goes to login form not the to User Page.

Here is my code for Login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../config/template.php');
require_once('../config/connect.php');
// HEADER
$templateEngine1 = new TempEngine();
$templateEngine1->loadTemplate('../template/Header.htm');
$templateEngine1->assign('Path', '../css/style.css');
$templateEngine1->assign('Text1', 'This is Header');
$templateEngine1->render();

$templateEngine2 = new TempEngine();
$templateEngine2->loadTemplate('../template/Section-Login.htm');
$templateEngine2->assign('L-01', 'Log-in Form');
$templateEngine2->assign('v1', 'User');
$templateEngine2->assign('v2', 'Password');
$templateEngine2->assign('v3', 'Submit');
$templateEngine2->assign('L-lnk01', 'Need Sign Up');
$templateEngine2->render();

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['User'];
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['Password'];
    
    $LoginUser = $_SESSION['User'];
    $LoginPass = $_SESSION['Password'];
    if (empty($LoginUser) || empty($LoginPass)){
        echo "<div class='Error'>All fields are required.</div>";
    }else{
        $UserIn = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE Username ='$LoginUser'";
        $result = $cn->query($UserIn);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if(!$row){
            echo "<div class='Error'>Username doesn't exist</div>";
        }else{
            if (password_verify($LoginPass, $row['Password'])) {
                header('Location: UserProfile.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "<div class='Error'>Invalid Password</div>";
            }
        }
    }   
}

// FOOTER
$templateEngine4 = new TempEngine();
$templateEngine4->loadTemplate('../template/Footer.htm');
$templateEngine4->assign('Text3', 'This is Footer');
$templateEngine4->render();
?>
```

and here is my code for User page:

```
<?php
 session_start();
require_once('../config/template.php');
require_once('../config/connect.php');

//HEADER
$templateEngine1 = new TempEngine();
$templateEngine1->loadTemplate('../template/Header.htm');
$templateEngine1->assign('Path', '../css/style.css');
$templateEngine1->assign('Text1', 'This is Header');
$templateEngine1->render();

$UserTxt = $_SESSION['User'];
$UserSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE Username ='$UserTxt'";
$result = $cn->query($UserSql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$MemberUser = $row['Username'];
$MemberFirstname = $row['FirstName'];
$MemberLastname = $row['LastName'];

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $UserTxt = $MemberUser;
    echo"Login Success";
}else{
    header('Location: UserProfile.php');
}

$templateEngine2 = new TempEngine();
$templateEngine2->loadTemplate('../template/User-Profile.htm');
$templateEngine2->assign('L-01', $_SESSION['User']);
$templateEngine2->assign('Ed1', 'User');
$templateEngine2->assign('Ed2', 'Firstname');
$templateEngine2->assign('Ed3', 'Lastname');
$templateEngine2->assign('v1', $MemberUser);
$templateEngine2->assign('v2', $MemberFirstname);
$templateEngine2->assign('v3', $MemberLastname);
$templateEngine2->render();

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'logout'){
session_destroy();
header('Location: Login.php');
}

// FOOTER
$templateEngine4 = new TempEngine();
$templateEngine4->loadTemplate('../template/Footer.htm');
$templateEngine4->assign('Text3', 'This is Footer');
$templateEngine4->render();

?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have a couple of problems here. In your password verified case, you need to set something in the session to say that the login is successful. You are not presently doing that.

Comment: In both of your SQL queries you have a serious SQL injection vulnerability. You need to use parameterisation so that you don't get hacked.

Comment: how can i set parameterization?

Comment: [Start here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). It depends on whether you're using the PDO driver or the MySQLi driver.

Comment: Third problem: in your User page, your `header()` redirect does not have an `exit()` afterwards. The server will carry on executing the page until it detects the browser has disconnected, which will give you a race condition.

Comment: Fourth, there is absolutely no need or purpose to store the password in the Session. It just causes a (small) but unnecessary extra security risk. Also it doesn't seem to make much sense to store the username in the Session _before_ you've verified that the login was successful.